# Swift. Internal type in public protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I am trying to work with swift generics, but I am stuck...
It might be impossible to do it this way, but I was hoping someone would have a good suggestion.

So I have this protocol and a type that I want to have internal:

```
internal protocol ATCoreInstrumentProtocol { // SOME STUFF }
internal typealias AT_1G_WaveInstrumentType = //Somethings that conforms to ATCoreInstrumentProtocol
```

---

Then I have this InstrumentType that I want to be public.
The problem here is that `ASSOCIATED_INSTRUMENT` aka `ATCoreInstrumentProtocol`
**needs** to be `internal` and therefore I cannot use it in this way.
There is not an option to make the `ATCoreInstrumentProtocol` public.

```
public protocol InstrumentType {
  static var instrumentType: SupportedInstrumentTypes { get }
  associatedtype ASSOCIATED_INSTRUMENT: ATCoreInstrumentProtocol
}

public final class InstrumentTypes {
  private init() {}

  public final class AT_1G_Wave : InstrumentType {
      public class var instrumentType: SupportedInstrumentTypes { get { return .wave_1G } }
      public typealias ASSOCIATED_INSTRUMENT = AT_1G_WaveInstrumentType
  }
}
```

---

This is how I want to use it.

```
internal class ATCoreInteractor<IT: InstrumentType> {

  internal var instrumentObservable : Observable<IT.ASSOCIATED_INSTRUMENT> {
      return self.instrumentSubject.asObservable()
  }

  private var instrumentSubject = ReplaySubject<IT.ASSOCIATED_INSTRUMENT>.create(bufferSize: 1)

  internal init(withSerial serial: String){
      self.scanDisposable = manager
          .scanFor([IT.instrumentType])
          .get(withSerial: serial)
          .take(1)
          .do(onNext: { (inst) in
              self.instrumentSubject.onNext(inst)
          })
          .subscribe()
}
```

---

And then I have the `ATSyncInteractor` which is `public`

```
public final class ATSyncInteractor<IT : InstrumentType> : ATCoreInteractor<IT> {
  public override init(withSerial serial: String) {
      super.init(withSerial: serial)
  }
}

public extension ATSyncInteractor where IT : InstrumentTypes.AT_1G_Wave {
  public func sync(opPriority: BLEOperationPriority = .normal, from: Date, to: Date, callback: @escaping (ATCoreReadyData<AT_1G_Wave_CurrentValues>?, [WaveTimeSeriesCoordinator], Error?) -> Void) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }
}



let interactor = ATSyncInteractor<InstrumentTypes.AT_1G_Wave>(withSerial: "12345")
```

Comment: How is a type in a different module expected to implement `InstrumentType` if it can't know about `ATCoreInstrumentProtocol`?

Comment: @zneak
They are not intended to implement it but they should use it like this:
`let interactor = ATSyncInteractor<InstrumentTypes.AT_1G_Wave>(withSerial: "12345")`

Comment: Does `ATCoreInstrumentProtocol` have associated types too?

Comment: @zneak No, none.

Comment: Does the generic parameter on `ATCoreInteractor` have a lot of significance in function signatures? For instance, do you have functions that *only* accept `ATSyncInteractor<InstrumentTypes.AT_1G_Wave>`, instead of `ATSyncIterator<IT>` where `IT` is generic?

Comment: Where I'm getting at is that maybe you don't need the generic parameter on `ATCoreInteractor`. You can have a `public enum` that lists the `InstrumentType` and that can instantiate a concrete value of each `ASSOCIATED_INSTRUMENT`.

Comment: If I understood you right, then yes. Take the `public sync(...)` functions for example. Later this year we will add `AT_2G_Wave` and `AT_Wave_Plus` InstrumentType's, all of them might/will have different implementations of the `sync(...)`.

Comment: We will also have a `ATPairingInteractor<IT: InstrumentType>`, `ATFirmwareInteractor<IT: InstrumentType>`, `ATSettingsInteractor<IT: InstrumentType>` and so on..  They will also have different implementations

Comment: @zneak I will try your Enum suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up beeing my solution.. 
The `InstrumentType` only contains the `SupportedInstrumentTypes`. 
The `ATCoreInteractor` Is no longer generic, but the observer is of type `ATCoreInstrumentProtocol`. 
The `ATSyncInteractor` extensions casts the instrument to its associated type.

I am open to improvements and suggestions.

```
public protocol InstrumentType : class {
    static var instrumentType: SupportedInstrumentTypes { get }
}

public final class InstrumentTypes {
    private init() {}

    public final class AT_1G_Wave : InstrumentType {
        private init() {}
        public class var instrumentType: SupportedInstrumentTypes { get { return .wave_1G } }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ATCoreInteractor {

    internal var instrumentSubject = ReplaySubject<ATCoreInstrumentProtocol>.create(bufferSize: 1)

    internal init(for type: SupportedInstrumentTypes, withSerial serial: String){

        self.scanDisposable = manager
            .scanFor([type])
            .get(withSerial: serial)
            .take(1)
            .do(onNext: { (inst) in
                self.instrumentSubject.onNext(inst)
            })
            .subscribe()
    }
}
```

---

```
public final class ATSyncInteractor<IT : InstrumentType> : ATCoreInteractor {

    public init(withSerial serial: String) {
        super.init(for: IT.instrumentType, withSerial: serial)

    }
} 

public extension ATSyncInteractor where IT : InstrumentTypes.AT_1G_Wave {

    private func instrument() -> Observable<AT_1G_WaveInstrumentType> {
        return self.instrumentSubject.map { $0 as! AT_1G_WaveInstrumentType }
    }

    public func sync(opPriority: BLEOperationPriority = .normal, from: Date, to: Date, callback: @escaping (ATCoreReadyData<AT_1G_Wave_CurrentValues>?, [WaveTimeSeriesCoordinator], Error?) -> Void) {

    }
}
```